# error in spout logic

Tags: python, apache-storm

I need some help from you in this problem . I read that spout is responsible for reading data or preparing it for processing in Bolt . so i wrote some code in spout to open the file and read line by line

```
class SimSpout(storm.Spout):
    # Not much to do here for such a basic spout
    def initialize(self, conf, context):
    ## Open the file with read only permit
        self.f = open('data.txt', 'r')
    ## Read the first line
        self._conf = conf
        self._context = context
        storm.logInfo("Spout instance starting...")
    # Process the next tuple
    def nextTuple(self):
        # check if it reach at the EOF to close it
      for line in self.f.readlines():
        # Emit a random sentence
        storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % line)
        storm.emit([line])

# Start the spout when it's invoked
SimSpout().run()
```

Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing Spout, whose responsibility in Storm is to emit tuples for downstream bolts to process.

Spout's nextTuple responsibility is to emit a single event each time its get called. In your code you are emitting all the lines in a file. If your single tuple is a single line. You should keep a offset into the file and read that 
offset line and emit, update offset = offset + 1.
something like below

```
class SimSpout(storm.Spout):

  # Not much to do here for such a basic spout
  def initialize(self, conf, context):
    ## Open the file with read only permit
    self.f = open('data.txt', 'r')
    ## Read the first line
    self._conf = conf
    self._context = context
    self._offset = 0
    storm.logInfo("Spout instance starting...")

 # Process the next tuple
 def nextTuple(self):
    # check if it reach at the EOF to close it
    with open(self.f) as f:
      f.readlines()[self._offset]
      #Emit a random sentence
      storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % line)
      storm.emit([line])
    self._offset = self._offset + 1
```

Comment: Many thanks for replying , i got this "with open(self.f) as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found "

Comment: the error i solved it that was because i opened the file twice , but i got another AttributeError: 'SimSpout' object has no attribute '_offset' i searched for solving it but didn't find anything help